# How do i script dynamic URLs for my site with php?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

In my web server document root i have created folder `/user/` with `/index.php` script in it. Regardless the current (authorized) user, i need to make a page which displays information about **any** users on my site to **anyone**, i have an idea to use query string:

```
site.com/user/?id=3
```

But i don't want to do like this. I want GitHub-like urls, like this:

```
site.com/user/UserName/
```

Also, i need to allow URL continutation to specify which 'action' is requested, like `subscribe`, or `comments`, and parameters, for specified username:

```
site.com/user/Admin/comments/32
site.com/user/Admin/virtual/path/
```

which should be a simple rewrite to physical path: `/user/index.php'.

I am newbie in PHP, but i know basics of mod_rewrite and .htaccess, and i still don't understand how can i determine which user (`Admin`) and what action (`comments`) is requested by URL, in my PHP script `index.php`.

Please teach how can i reach this URL syntax for my site? Or better, how to redirect `/user/Admin/comments` to physical `/user/comments.php`..

1. How to set up such dynamic rewriting with saving the username/action for php script?
2. How script can access user name and action (`comments`, `32`) requested by URL
3. How should i rename my question, because this title seems to be incorrect.

Sorry for long text, i am new in clean PHP scripting, Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at the [front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern). It addresses what you want to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* you *really* want to do it yourself and that's fine if you do, this is an example of what you will need to do. I understand not everyone needs or wants to use a framework.

First lets say your user URL is this like Github example.

```
http://www.yoursite.com/user/dmitrij
```

Then to for your .htaccess you will need a rewrite rule like this.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # check to make sure the request is not for a real file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # check to make sure the request is not for a real directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #route request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/? /user/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then if you want to show comments, your URL can look like this

```
http://www.yoursite.com/user/dmitrij/comments/32
```

Then it you can use .htaccess

```
    RewriteEngine On
    # check to make sure the request is not for a real file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # check to make sure the request is not for a real directory
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    #route request to index.php
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/comments/([0-9]+)/? /user/index.php?id=$1&comment_id=$2 [L]
```

Then you can put them all together in your .htaccess file for both URL's.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/comments/([0-9]+)/? /user/index.php?id=$1&comment_id=$2 [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^user/([^/]+)/? /user/index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Then in your `index.php` you will check the `$_GET` request. **This is a very simple example.**

```
<?php

 $username = $_GET["id"];
 $com_id = $_GET["comment_id"];

 print_r($username);
 exit;

?>
```

Make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled on the server and `AllowOverride All` is set in your vhost or config file.

You can do whatever you want with the values in `$_GET`. You will have to ensure `username` is unique in your database. You can also add more rewrites for different URL's too, which I wont cover here. 
This should get you a good start.

Comment: I didn't notice before that `RewriteRule` can rewrite regex values into result path query string.. really. Thank you!

Comment: @DmitrijA Yes there are so many ways you can create rewrites for you URL's you should be able to do them for any type you want. Glad this was able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use either a [URL-Rewrite-Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine) or start programming with an **MVC framework** like `symfony` or `cakePHP`, there the functionality is included

Comment: Really don't want use any frameworks if possible, until they are not only for my task..

Comment: then you need an url rewrite engine

Comment: `symfony` looks really nice, thank you for advice. I was really missing MVC pattern in PHP.

Comment: symfony works really nice indeed, but you will need sometime to get into it because some parts can be a bit complicated, but therefore you can save a lot of time by including libraries from other,... they are called bundles

Answer (score 1):

Like the answer above - you need to enable mod_rewrite and then provide the mapping pattern inside your .htaccess file.

I believe you also have to ensure that your Virtual Host is configured to

```
`Allow Override ALL`
```

This page provides good details - scroll down to the part entitled "How to Rewrite urls".

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: I have already site running with rewrite engine installed/enabled. Thanks for the article, i see there's something new for me!

Comment: There is no space in `AllowOverride`